# Fix slight twist in rim

Tags: repair, wheel-truing

I'm restoring a wheel from the local used bike shop.  Over the space of 4 spokes there's a slight left and right twist in the rim.  Think of it as a left tilt with an offsetting right tilt on either side of the rim centerline that the spokes run along.  It's very slight and shows up mainly as a 1mm height difference from the left to the right side of the rim.  Another result is a right side and left side spoke 4 spaces apart that I can't tighten above 15 on my tension gauge without creating a low spot.  All the other spokes are tightened to 23 - 26 on the gauge. Other than this I've been able to get the wheel true and round to within 1mm.  Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Welcome - If you can add photos with [edit] that may help the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this rim has had an impact that has distorted the metal, which will increase the difficulty in truing.

Your only options are:

1. Pull the rim into true with spoke tension only
2. Bend the rim closer to true, and then finish it with spoke tension
3. Junk the rim.

It may end up being a compromise, where you accept some out-of-trueness while having some high and some low tension spokes.

---

If it were me, I would use a truing stand or an old fork to hold the wheel, and identify the topology of the rim.  Mark high and low spots with a marker.   Then slack off ~8 spokes in this sector.  Place the rim over some supports and use a hammer to hit the high spot while supporting the low spots on the other side.

Ideally use a deadblow hammer to minimise bounce, or a lead/rawhide hammer to avoid marring the surface.  Or use a piece of hardwood as a spreader and hit that with a regular hammer.

Test using a straight-edge from both sides of the rim, and aim for making it "half-way better" rather than hammering till its perfect.

Then re-tension the spokes and true the wheel like normal.

If you spend over 4 hours on this, its time to write off the rim and replace it.   You can reuse the hub, and likely save the spokes if a replacement rim matches the old one.  The nipples might be reusable depending on how munched the flats/drive section are.